# How can I monitor user bandwidth of applications?

Tags: network-programming, adobe, bandwidth

I developed an application through which client can upload and download files to server. Now, I want to allocate the complete bandwidth of client when he upload or download files through my application. My client end is Adobe flash builder and cpp at server side. Any one can help me so that my client can do file transfer rapidly through my application. Thank you.

Comment: I think your actual question is different from the topic of the question monitoring and rapid transfer are two different parts. Please make us clear what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the user's operating system will allocate bandwidth sensibly. Your application will get all of it unless it's needed for something else at the same time.